# regarding the decoder layer definition in autoencoder model under Keras framework

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, theano, keras, keras-layer

In the autoencoder example included in [this blog](https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html), the author builds one-hidden-layer as follows.

```
 # this is the size of our encoded representations
 encoding_dim = 32  # 32 floats -> compression of factor 24.5, assuming the input is 784 floats
 input_img = Input(shape=(784,))
 encoded = Dense(encoding_dim, activation='relu')(input_img)
 decoded = Dense(784, activation='sigmoid')(encoded)
 autoencoder = Model(input=input_img, output=decoded)

 # this model maps an input to its encoded representation
 encoder = Model(input=input_img, output=encoded)
```

I can understand how the above part works, but I am confused about the following part to build the decoder part

```
 # create a placeholder for an encoded (32-dimensional) input
 encoded_input = Input(shape=(encoding_dim,))
 # retrieve the last layer of the autoencoder model
 decoder_layer = autoencoder.layers[-1]
 # create the decoder model
 decoder = Model(input=encoded_input, output=decoder_layer(encoded_input))
```

In specific, I thought the `decoder` should be defined as `decoder = Model(input=encoded, output=decoded)`. I don't understand why we have to introduce extra variable `encoded_input`. According to autoencoder model, we just decode the encoded part to the output, and thus the input for the decoder layer should be `encoded`. 
Moreover, if the decoder model is defined as above, why encoder is not defined as `encoder=Model(input=input_img, output=autoencoder.layers[0](input_img))`?

Answer (score 0):

`encoded_input` represents a placeholder which can be used if you want to run just the decoder and not the encoder on some data you generate (say if you're exploring the encoded space).